# How to check if a <div> contains a determinate text?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an easteregg for my website. There's a title you can change. I want it to start the easteregg if it contains a determinate string.

```html
<h1 class="titlename" id="changeT">Welcome</h1>

<div class="action1">
  <div id="titlechange">
    <p>
      <div id="explain">Write the title you want and press "Confirm". The title "Welcome" will be replaced with the text you wrote. <span class="material-icons">
          leaderboard
          </span></div>
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="Your title" maxlength="50">

    <button onclick="chageText()" class="hideshowbtn">Confirm <span class="material-icons">
        check
        </span></button>

    <script>
      function chageText() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        document.getElementById("changeT").innerHTML = x;
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to start a script if  contains "hello". How?

Comment: You have the input value which you named `x`. If it equals `"hello"` you want to do something. Therefore `if(x==="hello") doSomething();` maybe ?

Comment: You might be looking for the `includes`  function. More info here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: @JeremyThille I tried

<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("changeT");
  if ( x === "hello" ); {
  }
</script>

Comment: Ah right, so `if(x.includes("hello")) doSomething();`

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("changeT");` this gives you a DOM element, not its text

Comment: @JeremyThille so how do I get its text

Comment: [Like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+the+text+of+a+div+in+javascript), but why would you want to _get_ it from `changeT`? You already have it. It's in your `x` variable. You are even using the `x` variable to _set_  `changeT`'s text. Why would you want to grab it again?

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm making a random website with a friend, if you want, check it https://puzzenti.github.io there's a button to test the easteregg but I want it to start when I write "hello" in the title

Comment: Yes, I got that. You already explained it in your quesiton. Not sure why you're explaining it again?

Comment: @JeremyThille ye ok but how do I make it work now? I'm new in javascript

Comment: 4 people have posted an answer, Fred's one is the good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use "string".includes("keyword") to check if a string contains a certain substring.

Depending on whether you want to check for the easteregg-keyword when the user presses the button, or during input, I have written two ways for you to check the value of the input.

```html
<h1 class="titlename" id="changeT">Welcome</h1>

<div class="action1">
  <div id="titlechange">
    <p>
      <div id="explain">Write the title you want and press "Confirm". The title "Welcome" will be replaced with the text you wrote. <span class="material-icons">
          leaderboard
          </span></div>
    </p>
    <!-- If you want to check for easteregg when user types, add onkeyup="checkInput()"-->
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="Your title" maxlength="50" onkeyup="checkInput()">

    <button onclick="chageText()" class="hideshowbtn">Confirm <span class="material-icons">
        check
        </span></button>

    <script>
      function chageText() {
        var input = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        var header = document.getElementById("changeT");
        header.innerHTML = input;

        var keyword = "button"
        // If you want to check input when user presses the button:
        if(input.includes(keyword)){
            // Do easteregg stuff
            header.style.color = "red";
        }
      }

      function checkInput() {
        var input = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        var header = document.getElementById("changeT");

        var keyword = "check";
        if(input.includes(keyword)){
          //Do easteregg stuff
          header.style.color = "blue";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The keyword should be "hello", but _at last_ one good answer to this very simple problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use `includes` method with innerText.

```
if(document.getElementById('example').innerText.includes('hello')){
  //... do somethings
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vn50dayk/

Comment: @NuKl3Ar, if there is something wrong, it is better to show some error messages.

Comment: have you changed element id "example", with your element id

Comment: I also added js fiddle example for you

Comment: @ikhvjs as it's an easteregg it's meant to not be shown [my website](https://puzzenti.github.io) it's just a random website I'm making with a friend, it's not serious but I want it to work. You can try the easteregg with the button but I want it to work by the text in the title

Comment: How does this solve OP's problem? They have the variable `x` which is the input's value. That's what you want to test. Then, `x` is used to _set_ the div's text. Why would you then want to grab this div's text again, to test what it contains? You already have what you need. It's `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this if the string is a word:

```js
      function chageText() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        if( x.split(" ").indexOf("hello") !== -1 ) document.getElementById("changeT").innerHTML = x;
      }
```

```html
<h1 class="titlename" id="changeT">Welcome</h1>

<div class="action1">
  <div id="titlechange">
    <p>
      <div id="explain">Write the title you want and press "Confirm". The title "Welcome" will be replaced with the text you wrote. <span class="material-icons">
          leaderboard
          </span></div>
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="Your title" maxlength="50">

    <button onclick="chageText()" class="hideshowbtn">Confirm <span class="material-icons">
        check
        </span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The string I'm going check are 2 words

Comment: ...or `if(x.includes("hello"))` ?

Comment: then you replace `x.split(" ").indexOf("hello") !== -1` with what @JeremyThille told you